# hql could not resolve property: key of: com.farmtracker.model.Farm

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am sorry to add another one of these...   but everything looks right to me I must be missing something. This is the query:

```
from AnimalType at where at.farm.key=:key
```

Here is the getter from AnimalType:

```
public Farm getFarm() {return farm;}
```

here is the getter from Farm:

```
public Integer getKey() {return farmKey;}
```

I am not sure what I am missing...   It just doesnt seem to be able to find the key property off of farm.

Comment: What is the name of of the key in the Farm model? Is it 'key' or 'farmKey'? If it is farmKey, try at.farm.farmKey=:key in your query.

Comment: Please post the error stack. Also check to see if this is not because `key` is a reserved keyword in many databases. Atleast in [Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) it is.

Comment: @techtabu thanks that worked...    its odd I thought it worked off of the getters not the private variables. please write it as an answer so I can accept it